# socat dispaly UTF-8 char properly

Tags: socat

**test file with Polish diacritics**

```
file test.txt
test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
cat test.txt
xyz
żółć
ążśźćńół
abc
```

**request**

```
wget --post-file test.txt -O - --header="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" --header='SOAPAction: "abc"'  http://localhost:2222/xyz
```

**dump from socat**

```
POST /xyz HTTP/1.0\r
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (solaris2.10)\r
Accept: */*\r
Host: localhost:2222\r
Connection: Keep-Alive\r
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r
Content-Length: 34\r
SOAPAction: "abc"\r
\r
xyz
........
................
abc
```

**question**

How to get a socat to display the appropriate characters instead of dots.